# How can I get return type in php without @return in comment lines

Tags: php, yii, phpstorm

I am using Yii Framework with phpStorm ide for one of my php project.

```
$form  = $this->beginWidget(
                'CActiveForm', array(
                    'id' => 'form-id',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => true,
                )
            );
```

$form is an instance of CActiveForm after this call because of the first parameter of method.
When I type

```
$form->
```

in ide it doesn't give parameter or method hints. So I need to tell the ide that $form's type is CActiveForm. I can't use comment @return because method's return type is changing by first parameter dynamically. 
I tried

```
$form = (CActiveForm) $this->beginWidget(...
```

But it didn't work. How can I get hint from the ide in this stiuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know your IDE, but the  [phpDoc way to do this](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html) would be using `@var`:

```
/** @var $form CActiveForm */
$form = $this->beginWidget(...
```

Comment: but in my ide `/** @var $form CActiveForm */` worked. Thanks.